# How to pass link parameter from react native fetch method to express js server

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to pass the link parameter to express js server, so how can i pass through fetch method in react native ? 
here is my lines of code to fetch the particular

```
searchByID = () => {
        this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: true }, () => {
          const {ticket} = this.state.ticketid;
            fetch('http://192.168.0.108:3000/users/${ticket}',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers:
                    {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((res) => {
                    if (res.success === true) {
                         alert(res.message);
                        this.setState({ dataSource: res.message })
                        AsyncStorage.setItem('userinfo', res);
                        this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: false });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(res.message);
                    }
                    this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: false })
                }).done();
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the body field.

```
searchByID = () => {
    this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: true }, () => {
        const { ticket } = this.state.ticketid;
        fetch('http://192.168.0.108:3000/users/${ticket}',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:
                {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2 })
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.success === true) {
                    alert(res.message);
                    this.setState({ dataSource: res.message })
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('userinfo', res);
                    this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: false });
                }
                else {
                    alert(res.message);
                }
                this.setState({ ActivityIndicator_Loading: false })
            }).done();
    })
}
```